# Rearranging equation with division using Maxima

Tags: maxima

I'm trying to rearrange equation using maxima, but `coefmatrix` function does not work well with equation that has some division such as `RL_parallel`

I am getting all zeroes for the coefficients

```
RL_series: Rs + %i*w*Ls;
RL_parallel: ratsimp( 1 / [1/Rp + 1/(%i*w*Lp)] );

display2d : false $
eq : RL_series  = RL_parallel $
vars : [Rs, Rp, Ls, Lp] $
coeffs : coefmatrix ([eq], vars);

coeffs . vars;
```

[image: Rearranging Equation with division]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that the equation isn't linear in the variables specified, so extracting a coefficient matrix doesn't make any sense, unfortunately.

I am guessing that you want to solve the equation for `vars`. It seems to me that you'll need additional data, but it could well be that I'm missing something.

Here's what I get. Note that `[ ... ]` is a list; use `( ... )` for grouping expressions.

```
(%i1) RL_series: Rs + %i*w*Ls;
(%o1)                            %i Ls w + Rs
(%i2) RL_parallel: ratsimp( 1 / (1/Rp + 1/(%i*w*Lp)) );
                                   Lp Rp w
(%o2)                            ------------
                                 Lp w - %i Rp
(%i3) eq : RL_series  = RL_parallel;
                                           Lp Rp w
(%o3)                     %i Ls w + Rs = ------------
                                         Lp w - %i Rp
(%i4) vars : [Rs, Rp, Ls, Lp];
(%o4)                          [Rs, Rp, Ls, Lp]
(%i5) denom(rhs(eq)) * eq;
(%o5)               (Lp w - %i Rp) (%i Ls w + Rs) = Lp Rp w
(%i6) expand (%);
                       2
(%o6)        %i Lp Ls w  + Lp Rs w + Ls Rp w - %i Rp Rs = Lp Rp w
```

Assuming that `vars` are real, we can separate the real and imaginary parts of the equation.

```
(%i7) [realpart(%), imagpart(%)];
                                                   2
(%o7)         [Lp Rs w + Ls Rp w = Lp Rp w, Lp Ls w  - Rp Rs = 0]
(%i8) first(%) / (Lp*Rp*w);
                             Lp Rs w + Ls Rp w
(%o8)                        ----------------- = 1
                                  Lp Rp w
(%i9) expand (%);
                                  Rs   Ls
(%o9)                             -- + -- = 1
                                  Rp   Lp
```

So one of the equations has a product `Xs*Xp` and the other has the ratio `Xs/Xp`. Maybe that helps direct the search for additional data.

At this point I don't know what more can be said. If anyone can comment on this point I would be interested to hear it.

EDIT: OP says that the goal is to solve for Rp and Lp in terms of Rs and Ls. Given that, we can solve the two equations we obtained in %o7.

```
(%i10) %o7[2];
                                    2
(%o10)                       Lp Ls w  - Rp Rs = 0
(%i11) solve ([%o9, %o10], [Rp, Lp]);
                   2  2     2         2  2     2
                 Ls  w  + Rs        Ls  w  + Rs
(%o11)    [[Rp = ------------, Lp = ------------], [Rp = 0, Lp = 0]]
                      Rs                   2
                                       Ls w
(%i12) subst (%o11[1], [%o9, %o10]);
                         2  2            2
                       Ls  w           Rs
(%o12)             [------------ + ------------ = 1, 0 = 0]
                      2  2     2     2  2     2
                    Ls  w  + Rs    Ls  w  + Rs
(%i13) ratsimp(%);
(%o13)                          [1 = 1, 0 = 0]
```

Comment: I was trying to get two equations, expressing Rp and Lp in terms of Rs and Ls.  Hope this makes the context of my question clearer to everyone.  If you are familiar with series-to-parallel conversion. then you would be clearer with what I am trying to achieve.

https://i.imgur.com/GxgLB3R.png

Comment: OK, great, that makes the problem a little simpler. I've updated my answer.